# How to read frames using PyQt and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been trying to read frames from webcam, using OpenCV and PyQt. I know there are a lot of examples. But I would like to use MVC (model-view-controller).

OpenCV handles controller, i created models.py for model and views.py for GUI.

I don't see any error before run the code, when i run the code GUI opens, then i press open webcam and i see this warning and error:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is views.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox
from models import Camera

class UI_Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, camera = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera

        # Create a timer.
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(Camera.nextFrameSlot)

        # Create a layout.
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Add a button
        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        btnCamera = QPushButton("Open camera")
        btnCamera.clicked.connect(Camera.openCamera)
        button_layout.addWidget(btnCamera)
        layout.addLayout(button_layout)

        # Add a label
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setFixedSize(640, 640)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # Set the layout
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("First GUI with QT")
        self.setFixedSize(800, 800)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414781/prompt-on-exit-in-pyqt-application

class MovieThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, camera):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera

    def run(self):
        self.camera.acquire_movie(200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = UI_Window()
    window.show()
```

models.py

```
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage

class Camera:

    def __init__(self, camera):
        self.camera = camera
        self.cap = None

    def openCamera(self):
        self.vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # vc.set(5, 30)  #set FPS
        self.vc.set(3, 640)  # set width
        self.vc.set(4, 480)  # set height

        if not self.vc.isOpened():
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setText("Failed to open camera.")
            msgBox.exec_()
            return

        self.timer.start(1000. / 24)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103148/capture-webcam-video-using-pyqt
    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        rval, frame = self.vc.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def initialize(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera)
```

start.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from models import Camera
from views import UI_Window

camera = Camera(0)
camera.initialize()

app = QApplication([])
start_window = UI_Window(camera)
start_window.show()
app.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: did you search `cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback`  in Google? What did you find?

Comment: at start you use `initialize()` which uses `cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera)` but you have also button which runs `Camera.openCamera` which use `self.vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` - so you create access two times but you not releasing first access.

Comment: [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888878/cv2-warn0-terminating-async-callback-when-attempting-to-take-a-picture) . but it didn't work (answer to your first comment)

Comment: is this full error message ? Don't you have more lines in error? Maybe there are other useful information - ie. in which line is problem.

Comment: unfortunately it is full message

Comment: I don't know if it can help but you use class `Camera` instead of instance `camera` in `self.timer.timeout.connect(Camera.nextFrameSlot)` and `btnCamera.clicked.connect(Camera.openCamera)` and it can make some problem. Besides you use `self.timer` inside `openCamera` but this class doesn't have `self.timer` - it is in `UI_Window`

Comment: the same problem with `self.label` which you use in `Camera` but it is created in `UI_Window`

Comment: when i move `nextFrameSlot` and `openCamera` from `camera` to `UI_Window` it works. but is it appropriate to MVC?

Comment: MVC? Who care. In Camera I would add `camera.read()` so I wouldn't  use `camera.vc.read()`. If `Camera` has to be model then it has to give frame but it doesn't have to access UI widgets. I wouldn't use even `QMessageBox` in `Camera`. All GUI I would use only in `UI_Window`

Comment: Is model unnecesary? I will add a lot of functions. So i thought adding model would be good.

Comment: I would create class `Camera` which has only method which works with camera and frame but not with widgets - eventually I could return `QPixmap` or `QImage`. I never call it `model` - but probably it works like model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me. For test I put all in one file.

I removed

```
camera.initialize()
```

I moved `nextFrameSlot` from `Camera` to `UI_Window`

I also created `start()` in `UI_Windows` to move `self.timer.start()` from `Camera` to `UI_Window`

---

```
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage

class Camera:

    def __init__(self, camera):
        self.camera = camera
        self.cap = None

    def openCamera(self):
        self.vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # vc.set(5, 30)  #set FPS
        self.vc.set(3, 640)  # set width
        self.vc.set(4, 480)  # set height

        if not self.vc.isOpened():
            print('failure')
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setText("Failed to open camera.")
            msgBox.exec_()
            return

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103148/capture-webcam-video-using-pyqt
    def initialize(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera)



from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox
#from models import Camera

class UI_Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, camera = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera
        print('UI')
        # Create a timer.
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)

        # Create a layout.
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Add a button
        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        btnCamera = QPushButton("Open camera")
        btnCamera.clicked.connect(self.start)
        button_layout.addWidget(btnCamera)
        layout.addLayout(button_layout)

        # Add a label
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setFixedSize(640, 640)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # Set the layout
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("First GUI with QT")
        self.setFixedSize(800, 800)

    def start(self):
        camera.openCamera()
        self.timer.start(1000. / 24)

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        rval, frame = camera.vc.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414781/prompt-on-exit-in-pyqt-application

class MovieThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, camera):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera

    def run(self):
        self.camera.acquire_movie(200)

#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    app = QApplication([])
#    window = UI_Window()
#    window.show()

#start.py

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

#from models import Camera
#from views import UI_Window

camera = Camera(0)
#camera.initialize()
print('test')
app = QApplication([])
start_window = UI_Window(camera)
start_window.show()
app.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**EDIT:** code tested in separated files.

I also added `read_gray()` and negative colors `read(negative=True)`, `read_gray(negative=True)`

**BTW:** I many places I check if `frame` is not empty - but it can't be used `if not frame` but `if frame is not None` because `frame` is `numpy.array` and `if not numpy.array:` may give wrong result.

All GUI widgets I moved to from `model` to `view`.

**models.py**

```
import cv2

class Camera:

    def __init__(self, camera):
        self.camera = camera
        self.vp = None

    def open(self, width=640, height=480, fps=30):
        self.vc = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera)

        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = fps
        # vc.set(5, fps)  #set FPS
        self.vc.set(3, width)   # set width
        self.vc.set(4, height)  # set height

        return self.vc.isOpened()

    def read(self, negative=False):
        rval, frame = self.vc.read()
        if frame is not None:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
            if negative:
                frame = cv2.bitwise_not(frame)
            return frame

    def read_gray(self, negative=False):            
        rval, frame = self.vc.read()
        if frame is not None:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) 
            if negative:
                frame = cv2.bitwise_not(frame)
            return frame
```

**views.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from models import Camera

class UI_Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, camera = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera
        print('UI')
        # Create a timer.
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)

        # Create a layout.
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Add a button
        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        btnCamera = QPushButton("Open camera")
        btnCamera.clicked.connect(self.start)
        button_layout.addWidget(btnCamera)
        layout.addLayout(button_layout)

        # Add a label
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setFixedSize(640, 640)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # Set the layout
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("First GUI with QT")
        #self.setFixedSize(800, 800)

    def start(self):
        if not self.camera.open():
            print('failure')
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setText("Failed to open camera.")
            msgBox.exec_()
            return

        self.timer.start(1000. / 24)

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        frame = self.camera.read()
        #frame = self.camera.read_gray()
        if frame is not None:
            image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


class MovieThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, camera):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera

    def run(self):
        self.camera.acquire_movie(200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = UI_Window()
    window.show()
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from views import UI_Window
from models import Camera

if __name__ == '__main__':

    camera = Camera(0)

    app = QApplication([])
    start_window = UI_Window(camera)
    start_window.show()
    app.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: it works in one file. but when i split it to 3 files. i see error in `views.py`. it says 'unresolved reference to camera'. `camera`s in `nextFrameSlot` and `start` are undelined

Comment: you have to use `self.` to access `self.camera`

Comment: I added code tested in separated files. I also added `read_gray()` and convert colors to negative. In Camera/model I would add also other filters and image's modifications - ie. flip, recognize contours, and other cv2's functions

Answer (score 2):

Here is a consice alternative to @furas's answer if your just looking for a barebones answer to the question:

> "How to read frames using PyQt and OpenCV?"

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QTimer, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import cv2

def main():    
    app = QApplication([])
    
    window = QWidget()
    window.setLayout(QGridLayout(window))    
    window.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))

    label = QLabel()
    label.setFixedSize(640, 640)    
    window.layout().addWidget(label, 0, 0)

    window.show()

    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    vc.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    vc.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: nextFrameSlot(vc, label))
    timer.start(1000. / 24)

    return app.exit(app.exec_())

def nextFrameSlot(vc: cv2.VideoCapture, label: QLabel):
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit_code = main()
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

Tested with `Python 3.7.9`

requirements.txt:

```
numpy==1.19.4
opencv-python==4.4.0.46
PyQt5==5.15.1
PyQt5-sip==12.8.1
```